# EF trying to add to table outside of table I want to update

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a table called CommandResults that I want to update where entries exist and when they don't I would like to add them.

CommandResults contains a foreign key column of CommandID which references a table called Commands

EF is attempting to add a duplicate key into Commands and i'm not sure why. I don't want to touch this table.

There are no entries in CommandResults yet so orig is null for the add. But why is it trying to mess with the table Commands?

List is passed from another class. Each CommandResult is a new instance and not pulled from EF.

```
public void UpsertCommandResults(List<CommandResult> commandResults)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (CommandResult result in commandResults)
        {
            CommandResult orig = db.CommandResults.Where(x => x.CommandID.Equals(result.CommandID) && x.OutputDescription.Equals(result.OutputDescription)).FirstOrDefault();

            if (orig == null)
            {
                db.CommandResults.Add(result);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            else
            {
                orig.AlertTypeID = result.AlertTypeID;
                orig.ModifiedDatetime = result.ModifiedDatetime;
                orig.Output = result.Output;
                orig.OutputDescription = result.OutputDescription;
                db.Entry(orig).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Core.Logging.SimpleLog.Log(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try putting the `EntityState.Modified` before you begin setting values in the else?

Comment: Ok so one class passes the results to my class that deals with all of the database work. Moving the database work back into the main class makes this work. I don't understand why?

Comment: I would assume either 1) there are Command objects in result, that are already in the database, in which case you'll have to set those state to modify or remove them 2) there are multiple Command objects with the same id in result, which would fail while attaching the entry, you'll have to set temporary Id's in this case.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx